# Swagger-UI does not show my controllers from different modules?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm using swagger with Spring Boot and the UI does not shows the controllers.
My project looks like: I have a few gradle modules in root project. 
There are two of them for REST:

- documentation (in this module I have package *.documentation and there I have a few interfaces with swagger annotations)
- rest (in this module I have package *.controller and there each controller implements documentation interface from module documentation)

When I'm trying to run swagger-ui there is no resources on the UI.
BUT! when I move my controllers into documentation module then everything works fine or when I move interfaces with swagger annotations to rest module. Problem is only when I use two modules, one for swagger annotations and one to implement those interfaces.

What should I do to make it works with two modules? I tried also ComponentScan annotation in my SwaggerConfig class(this class is also in documentation module) but it does not works too.

My project structure:

```
|-- Project
|   |-- app
|       |-- src/main/java
|          |-- mypackage
|             |-- App.java
|   |-- documentation
|       |-- src/main/java
|          |-- mypackage
|             |-- config
|                |-- SwaggerConfig.java
|             |-- documentation
|                |-- ProductSwaggerInterface.java
|   |-- rest
|       |-- src/main/java
|          |-- mypackage
|             |-- controller
|                |-- ProductController.java
```

In 'app' module I just run the SpringBoot app, in 'documentation' module I have interfaces with swagger annotations and in module 'rest' I implementing those interfaces in my controller.

Comment: update your question with project package structure and ComponentScan entry .

Comment: Added project structure, in ComponentScan I use "mypackage" and I tried also {"mypackage", "mypackage.documentation", "mypackage.controller"}

Comment: I have already replyed to a similar question , and i hope it gonna be usefull , just check it out : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53878629/4373948

Comment: Unfortunatelly it is not asnwer to my question. I do not want to have everything in my controller, this is why I made interface for swagger annotations and controller which implementing this interface. It works only when them both are in the same module(not package just gradle module). If I have them in different modules then it does not work. I can see swagger-ui.html but without any endpoints.

Comment: I have the same problem. Would be great if any one has the answer

Comment: did you get answer to your question?